# Не получается развернуть api на локальном IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Стоят все версии .net core 2.1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\ProductImages\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Публикую сайт (публикация без ошибок) кидаю в папку (Default) (в ней был сайт, опубликованный 2 дня назад, он работает); этот не работает (заменил старый на новый).

Когда пытаюсь открыть, вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Common causes of this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
```

Почему такое может происходить?

Comment: Смотрели пул у сайта? У DefaultAppPool стоит .net v2.0, а должно быть "Без управляемого кода".

Comment: @vusaldev стоит без